# Port 10000 closed in Sony Alpha 7R4MA

Tags: sony-camera-api

according to Sony Remote API manual. I can access the internal website of the camera.

http://192.168.122.1:64321/dd.xml

From there I can get to: http://192.168.122.1:64321/DmsDesc.xml

and to: http://192.168.122.1:64321/DigitalImagingDesc.xml

And in the end to: http://192.168.122.1:64321/DmsRmtDesc.xml

There is an information whrere to send JSON POST request

<av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ServiceType>camera</av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ServiceType>
<av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ActionList_URL><av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ServiceType>camera</av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ServiceType>
<av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ActionList_URL>http://192.168.122.1:10000/sony</av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ActionList_URL></av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ActionList_URL>

for example:

curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{ "method": "getAvailableApiList", "params": [], "id": 1, "version": "1.0" }' http://192.168.122.1:10000/sony/camera
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.

- Trying 192.168.122.1:10000...
- connect to 192.168.122.1 port 10000 failed: Connection refused
- Failed to connect to 192.168.122.1 port 10000 after 16 ms: Connection refused
- Closing connection 0
  curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.122.1 port 10000 after 16 ms: Connection refused

Scan of that port by nmap:

sudo nmap 192.168.122.1 -p 10000
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-03-09 14:52 CET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.122.1
Host is up (0.018s latency).
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
10000/tcp closed snet-sensor-mgmt
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.29 seconds

Any ports?

sudo nmap 192.168.122.1 -p 0-65535
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-03-09 14:48 CET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.122.1
Host is up (0.022s latency).
Not shown: 65533 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
15740/tcp open  ptp
60152/tcp open  unknown
64321/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 18.46 seconds

How to open that port?

Comment: I seems that there was an firmware update, some people report connectivity problem for ILCE-7RMA (non a) after update from 1.1 to 1.2 firmware. I think there is now a some form of authentication required, I'm correct? I can't find  documentation.